# Relative Time Index for Sequences of Treatment in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working in R, and I would like to create a relative time index for the case when a treatment can turn on and off for an individual. Thus, the index would count upwards from some negative number until 0, when treatment becomes a 1 and will count up as long as treatment remains at 1 before resetting. It simplest to explain what I need using an example.

Suppose I have data that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), treatment = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

I would like to get to the following result:

```
  id treatment relative_time
1     1         0            -2
2     1         0            -1
3     1         1             0
4     1         1             1
5     1         0            -3
6     1         0            -2
7     1         0            -1
8     1         1             0
9     1         1             1
10    1         1             2
11    1         0             .
12    2         0            -1
13    2         1             0
14    2         1             1
15    2         1             2
```

I have seen that the following code works for when you have treatment occurring once per individuals, but sadly I have not been able to find a way to adapt it to my case:

```
df  %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(relative_time = seq_along(treatment) - which(treatment %in% 1))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` library to first create a new grouping variable using `cumsum()` to detect value changes, then sequence each group `0,1,2...(n-1)` when treatment is 1, and `-n+0, -n+1, ... -1` when treatment is 0,

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    g = cumsum(treatment != lag(treatment, default = TRUE)),
    .by = id
  ) |>
  mutate(
    relative_time = seq_along(g) - 1 + ifelse(treatment, 0,  -length(g)),
    .by = c(id, g)
  ) |>
  select(-g)
```

output

```
id treatment relative_time
1   1         0            -2
2   1         0            -1
3   1         1             0
4   1         1             1
5   1         0            -3
6   1         0            -2
7   1         0            -1
8   1         1             0
9   1         1             1
10  1         1             2
11  1         0            -1
12  2         0            -1
13  2         1             0
14  2         1             1
15  2         1             2
```